# How to hide default interface(rewind and volumn button) on lockscreen when app is playing no-sound aiudio on background

Tags: ios

To achieve my goal,i need to play no-sound audio when users put my app into background.However,i don't want users to know that the app is playing no-sound music on background.But the interface(rewind and volumn buttons)on the lcokscreen can be deceived by users.Therefore,i am searching a method to hide them? I don't want to talk about whether my app will be refused by Apple or not, i just want to hide default interface on lockscreen. It is really appreciated  if somebody can help me.

Comment: This is too vague,and shows no attempt at a solution. Show your code, by default lock screen controls are not displayed.

Comment: My app can play audio on background(wha i use is AVAudioPlayer)because i have configured backgound mode. When my app is playing in the background, it must have volumn and track buttons on lock screen. Now what i want to do is to hide volumn and track buttons when my app is playing audio on background.I have tried several methods,such as MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, MPRemoteCommand, which cna not achieve my goal.I hope u can understand me.